# If I have cos(xy) there is some equivalence for simplifying with no other conditions

Tags: trigonometry

I have the following expression $$\frac{x\cos(xy)+\sin x+9x^4-3x^2y^2}{x^2\cos(xy)+3x^2y^2}$$ and I need a way to simplify it, that's what I'm searching for some equivalence of cos(xy); is there at least one?

Comment: Are $x,y$ both real?

Comment: I do not think you are going to find what you are looking for. Unless $x$ or $y$ is restricted to certain values, there is not much that can be done. The best bet I can think of is to use $\cos \theta = \frac {e^{i\theta} + e^{-i\theta}}2$, as there are at least theorems about expoonents of products. But I doubt you will find it helpful. What exactly are you trying to accomplish by this? Perhaps we can suggest a different path.